# Is there a name for the function $g(z)=\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z}$?

Tags: lie-groups

This function comes in connection with exponentiation for matrix Lie groups, e.g. in computing the derivative of $\exp()$ away from the identity, or $\exp()$ of something in the affine group associated with a linear group.  Does it have a name in the literature?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. But if you are looking for something like a "tangent coset", then have a look at the Maurer-Cartan form.

Comment: It is the exponential generating function of the harmonic numbers with -z instead of z. The Bernoulli numvers aruse naturally when inverting this around the origin.